# How to customize JQM nativeMenu

Tags: android, sorting, jquery-mobile, menu, native

I added JQM nativeMenu on my Android application. I use it for sorting and i want to customize the appearance.

```
<select id='sort' data-icon="sort" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"  class="ui-btn-right" >
   <option class= "option" id = "1" value="1">Sort: 1</option>
   <option class= "option" id = "2" value="2">Sort: 2</option>
   <option class= "option" id = "3" value="3">Sort: 3</option>
</select>
```

I want it native because I have some problems with non native.

> $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = true;

I gave it class called "option"

> .option{  background:BLUE !important;     color: RED ! important; }

But nothing is changed.The menu remains white, with chosen item green. On tapped gets orange.
If it's possible i want to add Title.

Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/v9cyn6nj/ `data-native-menu="false"` converts select into a popup with _listview_. You should target `.ui-btn` within the popup. The popup ID `sort-listbox`, `sort` is select ID and `-listbox` is added dynamically to popup.

Comment: Well.. I'm trying with native menu because the popup with listview does not allays appear. >_<
But still thanks a lot ^^

Comment: if the list if long and the viewport is small, the list will be converted into a dialog.

Comment: I see... My problem with JQM select menu is that on second or third tap(for opening the listview) the list is not showed. This occurs on Android and iOS. That's why i I'm trying with JQM nativeMenu.